# Re-calculate height when empitied

Tags: jquery, css

I have an event for when the height of a DIV element change. The fact is that it works fine but when i remove all the content of the DIV, the height remains the same till I place new elements.

How can I avoid this?

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
   <div class="left_menu left"></div>
      <div class="right">
          <div class="child models"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
new ResizeSensor(jQuery('div.main-container'), function() {
        var altura_total    = $('div#body').height();
        var main_container  = $('div.main-container').height();
        if ( altura_total > (main_container+310) ) $('div.footer').css('bottom', '0').css('position', 'fixed');
        else $('div.footer').css('bottom', '').css('position', '');
        console.info("Total: "+altura_total+' - main_container:'+main_container);

    });
```

And when I remove all the content from within the div.models scope, the height of the main-container should change, but not.

I remove elements via jQuery:

```
$('div.elements').remove();
```

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever tried "`min-height`", "`max-height`" or values in "*px*", "*in*", "*em*". It should work!

Comment: I remove elements via jQuery. $('div.elements').remove(); These elements are inside the main_container, which is the one I want to calculate.

Comment: `$('div.elements').remove().parent().css('height', 'auto');` Will do the work then.

Comment: main_container has its 'height' property to auto in the CSS.

Comment: @Troyer, I could find the solution by just setting the height of the parent to 0.

Comment: @Apalabrados I would prefer define the height to auto because it's his default value, but if you think give the value 0 is better is up to you. :)